# rails routes with flash

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I fixed RoutingError in rails 3 using [this link](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/36-rails-3-0-rescue-from-routing-error-solution). I wanted to redirect users to root page so I added:

```
match '*a', :to => 'homes#index'
```

to my routes.rb.

Question is: can I define flash[:error] message in this 'match' line to be displayed on target page?

Regards,
Mateusz

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to [Redirect and raise flash message when catch-all in routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16203961/redirect-and-raise-flash-message-when-catch-all-in-routes)

But I did run into this problem and it was giving me an issue because I was using `MATCH` and when I used `GET`, the `alert` wouldn't flash. Eventually I found a working solution using the thread above and applying `GET` in another manner.

`match '*path' => redirect{ |p, req| req.flash[:alert] = "The page you requested is not valid."; '/' }, via: [:get]`

This is what I ultimately came up with, `via: [:get]` being key to making everything work.

And remember to place such code at the end of your `routes.rb`