# Redirect and raise flash message when catch-all in routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am able to [redirect](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection) all (invalid) urls using [this line at the end of the routes file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132039/rails-redirect-all-unknown-routes-to-root-url):

```
match '*a' => redirect('/')
```

I'd like to do the redirect and pass on an alert message in `routes.rb`.
Something like (the syntax is wrong here):

```
match '*a' => redirect('/'), :alert => "aaargh, you don't want to go to #{params[:a]}"
```

Is it possible to do this?

*If I were doing this in a view/controller, I could use `redirect_to` and pass on a flash message on the redirected page (see examples in [redirecting in the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html)). Creating a new controller method and redirecting there would work, but it seems inelegant... is it the recommended way?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A slight tweaking of [Jun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16207809/1240268) allowed me to do this:

```
match '*a' => redirect { |p, req| req.flash[:error] = "aaargh, you don't want to go to #{p[:a]}"; '/' }
```

*Which redirects invalid pages to `'/'` along with the desired (dynamic) message.*

If you go to `www.your_website/a_bad_place` this passes the message on `'/'`:

> aaargh, you don't want to go to `a_bad_place`

.

You can grab the entire offending (invalid) url by using:

```
#{req.env["HTTP_HOST"]}#{req.env["REQUEST_PATH"]}
```

and display it with this:

```
match '*a' => redirect { |p, req| req.flash[:error] = "aaargh, you don't want to go to #{req.env["HTTP_HOST"]}#{req.env["REQUEST_PATH"]}"; '/' }
```

and you'll see:

> aaargh, you don't want to go to `www.yourwebsite/a_bad_place`

Answer (score 2):

The best I can do is:

```
match 'PATH' => redirect { |p, req| req.flash[:alert] = "MESSAGE"; '/' }
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to make a slight modification to do it, this got me in the right direction :)